# Full path to current font file

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to print the full path (including file name and extension) to the file of the current font? I'm interested in the following engines: pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX and their LaTeX counterparts. I'm not looking necessarily for a single method that will work on all of these engines; the methods may vary according to engine.

Comment: For LuaLaTeX: Have you read a log of the compilation process? There you'll find the font paths.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the current font".

Comment: @Mico: Is it possible to write a (La)TeX macro (or to use a pre-existing macro or command), whose replacement text will be the full path to the file of the font that was active at the time the macro/command was about to be expanded/executed? In the case of LuaTeX, a lua script is acceptable rather than a macro/command.

Comment: @Mico: It is also OK by me, instead of a macro/command, to have to read through a log file to figure this information out.

Comment: @Mico: Another alternative, though less desirable, is figuring out a file list of all the fonts used to render the current manuscript, without indication of when each font file was used.

Comment: As @TeXnician has already noted in a comment, you may want to start by determining whether the font-related information provided close to the very end of the log file suits your needs. This material consists of a listing of all fonts that were used, including the full path names to each font file. This material is written to the log file not just under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: in classic tex tex never loads the font at at all just the font metrics (that is the height and width not the shape, so are you asking for the path to the file tex loads (the tfm file) or the font file which would be loaded by pdftex but not by tex or xetex, but with pdftex/luatex a full list of all used fonts is at the end of the log as commented above.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wasn't aware of the duality of files: tfm and font file, but now that you mention it, I'm interested in *both*, with a greater priority to the font file (the one with the shapes; the one that can be perused using an application such as Font Book on Mac).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I looked inside one log file for pdfTeX and found lines such as: `LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.` But there is no full path to the font file.

Comment: Did you look at the material *close to the very end* of the log file, just before the line "Output written on ..."?

Comment: @Mico: With LuaTeX the log file seems to list the full path, as desired, but not with pdfTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: If the following LaTeX document -- `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Hello World. \end{document}` -- is compiled under pdfLaTeX, the log file reports `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb` as the one and only font file that was loaded. That sure looks like a full path to me...

Comment: Why do want these pathes? Pure curiousity or for some purpose?

Comment: @Mico: You're right about `pdflatex`, although I don't see this info in the log file but rather in the output that goes to the terminal. However in the case of `xelatex` this information appears neither in the log file nor on the terminal.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: For curiosity and experimentation purposes. I want to know what output to expect in various circumstances, and for that I need to inspect the current font with Font Book or a similar application.

Comment: Then use the log-file, the .fls-file and for xetex also `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've just tried adding `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to the preamble of a basic `Hello, world!` LaTeX manuscript, and compiled  with `xelatex` with and without the `-recorder` option. There was no mention of a font file path in either the `.log` or the `.fls` files.

Comment: Add it before \documentclass, or load a font after the setting with fontspec + \setmainfont.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This worked. `xelatex` (without the `-recorder` option) wrote the font file path to the `.log` file. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test file

```
\def\showcurrentfontpath{%
  \immediate\write20{}%
  \immediate\write20{Current font at line \the\inputlineno}%
  \immediate\write18{kpsewhich \fontname\font.tfm}%
  \immediate\write20{}%
}

abc\showcurrentfontpath

{\it abc\showcurrentfontpath}

\bye
```

Compile with `pdftex` and the console will show

```
Current font at line 8
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm


Current font at line 10
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmti10.tfm
```

If you want a printout, compile the following file with `pdftex -shell-escape`

```
\def\showcurrentfontpath{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\fontname\font.tfm}%
  \par\noindent
  \tt Current font at line \the\inputlineno:%
  \par\noindent
  \input"|kpsewhich \x"
  \endgroup
}

abc\showcurrentfontpath

{\it abc\showcurrentfontpath}


\bye
```

[image]

Another method is to run the engine with the `-recorder` command line option, which will write a `.fls` file with information about every input file. However, preloaded fonts such as the two above will not show up, because they've already been input at format creation.

For XeTeX you need to hook in `xdvipdfmx`, but unfortunately it won't show the full path of `.pfb` files: use

```
xetex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" test
```

and the `.tfm` files will be shown with their full path as well as OpenType or TrueType fonts. Not the `.pfb`, as I said.

Comment: Thanks! Will this solution work with all three engines (pdf, lua, xe)?

Comment: @EvanAad As far as I know, the only one that doesn't allow this is Knuth TeX.

Comment: This is a great solution for the `tfm` files, but it lists no information at all about the glyph files.

Comment: @EvanAad That's the purpose of `-recorder`. On the other hand, `pdftex` and `luatex` list the font files in the log.

Comment: OK, that might do, except you wrote that `-recorder` won't help me with fonts preloaded by the format.

Comment: @EvanAad I was referring to the `.tfm` files.

Comment: The `-recorder` solution works with `pdflatex` but not with `xelatex`.

Comment: @EvanAad Indeed, this requires hooking into `xdvipdfmx`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61020/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2):

This is to complement [egreg's brilliant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376583/21685).

egreg's macro prints out the full paths to the `.tmf` files, but not the full paths to the glyph files. It works on all three engines.

To view the glyph files proceed as follows.

- `pdflatex` + `lualatex`: The full paths to the glyph files is written to the `.log` file. (Suggested by [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/full-path-to-current-font-file?noredirect=1#comment932334_376577) (`lualatex`) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/full-path-to-current-font-file?noredirect=1#comment932349_376577) (`pdflatex`).)
  Alternatively, add the `-recorder` option to the command line. The full paths will be written to the `.fls` file. (Suggested by egreg in his answer.)
- `xelatex`: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` before the `\documentclass` command. The full paths will be written to the `.log` file. (Suggested by Ulrike Fischer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/full-path-to-current-font-file?noredirect=1#comment932392_376577) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/full-path-to-current-font-file?noredirect=1#comment932397_376577).)

* And thanks to David Carlisle who [made me realize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/full-path-to-current-font-file/376586#comment932354_376577) a TeX font specification is spread over a `tmf` file as well as a glyph file.